# I get an error when I pass in a function pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers

I need to pass in a function as an argument. I have seen many websites use this format and they said it works with or without a & before the function name, either way, it gives me an error.

```
static void iterate_test(void *node);
void delete(void *item);
static void printing(FILE *fp, const char *key, void *item);

int
main()
{   
    char *name = "name.txt";
    int *intp = malloc(sizeof(int));
    typedef void (*func1)(void*, char*, void*) = iterate_test;
    FILE *fp = fopen(name, "w");
    set_t *set = set_new(); // testing making a new set

    //Testing Iterate   
        //Function exists 
            set_iterate(set, intp, iterate_test);
        //Function doesn't exists 
            set_iterate(set, intp, iterate_test);
    //Testing Print

        //Printing normally
            set_print(set, fp, printing);
        //Printing with an inexistant function
            set_print(set, fp, printingfffff);
    //Testing Delete

        //Deleting a normal node
            set_delete(set, delete);
        //Deleteing from null set 
            set_delete(NULL, delete);
    fclose(fp);
    free(name);
    free(intp);
    return 0;
}

// Tests to see if it is able to move through the list set
static void iterate_test(void *node, char *key, void *item)
{
    if (node->key != NULL && node->item != NULL){
    }else{
    }
}

void delete(void *item)
{
    free(item);
}


/* Prints a single item */ 
static void printing(FILE *fp, const char *key, void *item)
{
  char *items = (char*)item;
  fputc('(', fp);
  fputs(key, fp);
  fputc(',', fp);
  fputs(items, fp);
  fputc(')', fp);
  fputc(',', fp);
  free(items);
```

Even when I pass in the func1 pointer it gives me an error

error/warning I get: 
 warning: passing argument 3 of 'set_iterate' from incompatible pointer type

set_iterate prototype: 
void set_iterate(set_t *set, void *arg,
         void (*itemfunc)(void *arg, const char *key, void *item) );

Comment: What's the function `set_iterate`?

Comment: @Samieo It is from a module, so I chose not to copy and paste it all, but here is the prototype:  void set_iterate(set_t *set, void *arg,
   void (*itemfunc)(void *arg, const char *key, void *item) );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  typedef void (*func1)(void*, char*, void*) = iterate_test;
> ```

is illegal because *typedef* defines a type, not a variable

---

The declaration

> ```
>  static void iterate_test(void *node);
> ```

is wrong because the function is

> ```
>  static void iterate_test(void *node, char *key, void *item)
>  {
>     ...
>  }
> ```

replace it by

```
 static void iterate_test(void *node, char *key, void *item);
```

---

> Even when I pass in the func1 pointer it gives me an error

After the previous correction `void (*func1)(void*, char*, void*) = iterate_test;` is correct (without `typedef`)

---

> error/warning I get: warning: passing argument 3 of 'set_iterate' from incompatible pointer type
>
> set_iterate prototype: void set_iterate(set_t *set, void *arg, void (*itemfunc)(void *arg, const char *key, void *item) );

the function pointer expected by `set_iterate` requires a `const char *` for its second parameter, but `iterate_test` has a `char *` for its second parameter, this is why you have that message

Remove the *const* in the profile of `set_iterate` or modify the declaration and definition of `iterate_test` to be

```
 static void iterate_test(void *node, const char *key, void *item);
 ...
 static void iterate_test(void *node, const char *key, void *item)
 {
     ...
 }
```

Of course in the second case if you still want to save the pointer in *func1* you need to have

```
void (*func1)(void*, const char*, void*) = iterate_test;
```